# Application fails to connect mongodb when primary node changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, amazon-ec2, database-replication

I had followed the following tutorial to setup mongodb on ec2,

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/#install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2

I have limited to one primary and 1 secondary node, the nodes switch among themselves which create issues when my ror application tried to access database.
I have used the instance address of primary node in mongoid.yml file.
As the replicas interchange themselves the applications fails to connect to the database.

How can i resolve this issue as in case i set priority for primary, still it can fail and secondary db will become primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you have the most recent version of mongoid for your rails/ruby versions?

Why don't you configure multiple hosts in mongoid.yml? Have a look at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration

You could try using the save mode aswell.

Comment: Yes, i have the latest version. I'll check the document

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the priorities of the various replica set members?  What we do with our setup is that we set the Primary with the highest priority (2 works fine) and then the Secondary keeps the default primary of 1. Instructions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/adjust-replica-set-member-priority/